# update web db after app was deleted

Tags: android, database, uninstallation

i created an app that needed to update her web database -

mainly - to know the app other users & how she can connect with them.

i wanted to know - if a user is delete this app - how can i send to my web database that the user is no longer using this app (like whatsapp and viber) ?

Comment: I would be very surprised if you can do this. If a user chooses to delete an app then it shouldn't be running any more code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, why not store a "last seen" date for each user which you update every time you see them, and if a user has not been seen for a bit assume they have gone?

This also covers the case where a user stops using an app but doesn't uninstall it.